# How much should you edit a question?

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

The OP doesn't seem to be responding to the comments on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96063/optimizing-a-wizard-that-does-no-direct-damage-in-dd-5e/96074?noredirect=1#comment223471_96074), but I think I've narrowed down his real concern as to what actions can be taken in combat that are not dealing damage or using resources.

Is it okay to make such a drastic change to someone's question or should I just ask it anew?

Answer (score 4):

In general making a drastic change to a question without the OP's collaboration is not appropriate, and it's not in this case.  *You* may think that's the root of their problem, but you may be wrong and/or they may disagree.  Given the amount of comment argument over there I'm not sure you can claim that everyone else is in agreement with you on this, either.  So let it lay.

As for you asking it separately - why, is it a problem you have? We find that when people ask questions where they don't have standing - in other words, the question is not a question they really have - those questions and answers end up sucking. As it's hypothetical no one can get good clarification on it, answers tend to be cursory, etc.  It's "legal" to do but I would never do it personally and find it gauche.

Comment: That was the general feeling I got as well - thank you for the clarification. As for why I'd ask it separately: because I think it's an interesting problem/question. What actions can be done that aren't resource using for someone in combat that doesn't want to contribute directly to damage? I think that's a good question that many people could use - and I think it'll greatly help the OP if he were to read it. But if you really think it's a bad idea, you've got the experience here and I'll follow your lead.

Comment: It is a good question, but that's why it deserves to be asked by someone actually hungry for the answer...  IMO otherwise we get milquetoast versions of what should be good core Q&A.

Comment: That's fair - although the question did spark enough interest in me to begin researching what can be done. But I guess I can just wait to see if someone asks it who really wants to play a character like that and has that specific question.

Comment: Up to you......